# C program compiler warning only in Windows (MinGW-w64)

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, gcc, mingw-w64

I built a multi-language software image processing program and made it generally available with binaries for Mac OS X and Ubuntu. The binaries have been tested on their respective operating systems and every thing works perfectly. I recently also tried to release binaries for Windows (64 bit) but the GCC (through MinGW-w64) compiler gave me warnings for one of the C programs when I create the shared library (dll) file. This did not happen in Mac OS X or Ubuntu. Here are the warnings and the corresponding line of code in the C file:

```
warning: passing argument 3 of '_beginthreadex' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

Line 464:

```
ThreadList[i] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, &ThreadFunc, &ThreadArgs[i] , 0, NULL );
```

The second and stranger warning:

```
    c:\mingw\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\process.h:31:29: note: 
expected 'unsigned int <*><void *>' but argument is of type 'void * <*><void *>'
    _CRTIMP uintptr_t _cdecl _beginthreadex<void *_Security,unsigned _Stacksize,unsigned <_stdcall *_StartAddress> <void *>,void *_ArgList,unsigned _InitFlag,unsigned *_ThrdAddr  >;
```

Line 34:

```
#include <process.h>
```

This belongs in this larger code block:

```
/* Multithreading stuff*/
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#else
#include <pthread.h>
#endif

#include <stdbool.h>
```

The problem seems to emanate from `#include <process.h>` since for Mac OS X and Ubuntu `#include <pthread.h>` is used. Any help figuring this out? The full C program is [here](https://github.com/haiderriazkhan/CANDLE-J/blob/master/ONLM_Mod.c) .

Comment: It's a warning message and is likely harmless. If your program exits unexpectedly when run then it's likely because of something else.

Comment: Another C program  that I compiled without any warnings runs successfully as a part of this software.  Every other component of the software is working fine. And on Ubuntu and Mac OS X the whole software runs wonderfully. That leaves this C file and the warning messages. And I can see from print statements that the program quits during this particular C file. It can not be a a coincidence.

Comment: It looks like a red herring to me. But you're the expert.

Comment: The warning message stems from `#include <process.h>`. That is not used in the MacOS X and the Windows version. That is why I am suspicious.

Comment: are you sure it says `<*>` and not `(*)` ?

Comment: @RossRidge You were right. The program was not crashing because of the warnings. It was because I was using the wrong file format to test my code. I was in a hurry and grabbed the nearest image. Everything is fine now. But anyways, still glad to learn why I was getting the error messages.

Comment: @MattMcNabb It could have been. I typed the error messages by hand. **cmd** would not let me copy anything from its window unlike the Mac terminal.

Comment: I voted to close this because your warning message and your observation that testing the wrong type of file causes your particular program to crash are unlikely to help future readers.  (Good software does quit unexpectedly when given invalid input; it should at least print an error message.)

Comment: By default you have to click the top left corner menu and choose "Edit > Mark" to copy out of cmd windows. You can turn on "QuickEdit mode" in the properties to change the default

Comment: @DavidGrayson I will remove the part about the program quitting from the question. The topic of the question will be the reason behind the warning messages and Peter answered that. You can still vote to close it if you like.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks. That is neat. Before you judge me too harshly, I must add that I am a Mac user and have hardly ever used Windows. I only picked it up to create a Window binary for users of my software program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The messages when compiling for windows but not for other systems are hardly surprising.   The offending code will only be seen by the compiler when building for windows, due to usage of the `_WIN32` macro which is only defined by the compiler when code is built for windows.

The "second and stranger warning" is describing the cause.   The third argument of the (windows specific) `_beginthreadex()` function is specified to be a pointer to a function that returns an `unsigned int`.    The actual `ThreadFunc` being passed is a function that returns a `void *`.

The fix to make the code acceptable to a windows compiler is to change the return type of `ThreadFunc()` to return `unsigned int`.    That will break the code for other systems, so you need to do the changes conditionally (i.e. have two versions of the function, and select the right one by testing the `_WIN32` macro).

```
#ifdef _WIN32
/*  use the windows version of the function here */
#else
/*  use the non-windows version of the function here */
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks. I think you are answer is on the right track. But when I change the return type, now the warning message changes to `expected 'unsigned int <*><void *>' but argument is of type 'unsigned int * <*><void *>'.` There is an extra star in the return type that should not be there. Or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Thanks. It works when you change it to `unsigned int`. Could you edit that in your answer (in case someone else comes looking).